# How to display zero values in mysql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

This code make an operation on a and b and check if result is equal to c.
If yes, just print this row. My question is how to change this code to display
rows when result (a / b) = 0.

```
SELECT id, a, b, operation, c
FROM expressions
where
case
    when operation LIKE '+' AND (a + b = c) then c
    when operation LIKE '-' AND (a - b = c) then c 
    when operation like '/' AND (a / b = c) then c
    when operation like '*' AND (a * b = c) then c
ELSE FALSE END;
```

Output:

```
id  a   b   operation   c
1   2   3   +   5
4   4   7   *   28

11  0   1   /   0
14  239 0   *   0
15  18  18  -   0
```

1, 2 rows are ok and printed. 3, 4, 5 rows should be printed but they are not!
When a / b = 0 then second condition in sql query is false - row is not printed, e.g. 0 / 1 = 0. It is 0 and should be printed. In contrart to 1 / 0 which shouldn`t be printed.
My solution is to cast (a / b = c) to unsigned but it is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already pointed out, the issue is that `0` is treated as false.

I would simplify the logic to:

```
SELECT id, a, b, operation, c
FROM expressions
WHERE (operation LIKE '+' AND (a + b = c) ) OR
      (operation LIKE '-' AND (a - b = c) ) OR
      (operation LIKE '/' AND (a / b = c) ) OR
      (operation LIKE '*' AND (a * b = c) );
```

I don't think the `CASE` makes the code more understandable.

If you are concerned about divide-by-zero, then use `nullif()`:

```
      (operation LIKE '/' AND (a / nullif(b, 0) = c) ) OR
```

Comment: One more think is to add:
...(operation LIKE '/' AND (a / b = c) AND b != 0 AND c * b = a ) OR...

Comment: @user3455638 . .. Those conditions will not matter because MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluations of boolean expressions.  `NULLIF()` is a better way to avoid divide-by-zero.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't mix types like `boolean` and `int` because implicit conversion occurs.

Use explicit value instead of `TRUE/FALSE` (`0` is treated as `FALSE`).

```
SELECT id, a, b, operation, c
FROM expressions
where
case
    when operation LIKE '+' AND (a + b = c) then 1
    when operation LIKE '-' AND (a - b = c) then 1 
    when operation like '/' AND (a / b = c) then 1
    when operation like '*' AND (a * b = c) then 1
ELSE 0 END = 1;
```

alternatively:

```
SELECT id, a, b, operation, c
FROM expressions
where
case
    when operation LIKE '+' AND (a + b = c) then TRUE
    when operation LIKE '-' AND (a - b = c) then TRUE
    when operation like '/' AND (a / b = c) then TRUE
    when operation like '*' AND (a * b = c) then TRUE
ELSE FALSE END;
```

Comment: Both of above solutions printing good rows. In first one you fogot ; at the end of query.